# Сборщик js для маленьких библиотек

Tags: javascript

К примеру есть два файла
script.js с функцией
main.js использует ее к примеру

```
import fn from './script.mjs'
```

или

```
let fn = requere('./script.mjs');
```

нужно чтобы requere был заменен на содержимое файла

Answer (score 0):

Если в `script.js`  есть функция которую нужно импортировать из файла `main.js`, то можно так:

**script.js**

```
export default function (a, b) {
  return a + b
}
```

**main.js**

```
import myAnyName from './script.js'

myAnyName(2, 2) // вернет 4
```

`myAnyName` может быть любым именем, но в таком случае файл **script.js** может содержать только одну функцию.

Если нужно создать файл который будет содержать много функций (часто делаю подобное для функций-помощников **helprers.js**):

```
export function sum (a, b) {
  return a + b
}

export function diff (a, b) {
  return a - b
}
```

Импортировать вот так:

```
import { sum, diff } from './script.js' // окончание js не обязательно

sum(2, 2) // 4
diff(2, 2) // 0
```

В JS довольно мощный экспорт/импорт и есть еще много полезного функционала с которым можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules).

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы было объединение в один файл. Что то типа шаблонизатора но для JS. 
Т.е. я хочу сформировать js из других. Своим форматом

Comment: Вам нужно из всех файлов сделать один? Если да, то надо сборщик модулей, например Webpack

Comment: Нет. Он не подходит из-за специфики. Сейчас я вижу вариант пока следующий.
var fn = fs.readFileSync('script.js.template');

Comment: @Oleg если судить по заголовку что надо "Сборщик js для маленьких библиотек", тогда могу посоветовать rollup

Comment: проверил, подходит.